# How to install 64-bit vlc library for 64-bit python 3 on windows?

Tags: windows, installation, python, vlc-media-player, libraries

I tried `python -m pip install python-vlc` with the sole installed version of python 3.6 64-bit yet it seems to have installed the 32-bit version.

How can I explicitly install `vlc` library for python in 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by first removing my 32-bit VLC player, and then installing [64-bit VLC player](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.8/win64/vlc-2.2.8-win64.exe) thanks to help in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48082249/7032856).